# Can I calculate confidence interval for effect size using only F test score and N?

Tags: confidence-interval, effect-size, f-test

I was able to calculate the effect size for a sample for which I only have the total N and F-test score. 
However, I also would like to calculate the confidence interval or margin of error for that particular effect size.

For example, group 1 = 30, group 2 = 30. Total N = 60
F-score = 4.71
ES = 0.56 (Cohen's d)

How can I calculate an ES confidence interval for the above data?
Thanks.